# Javascript - find largest number

Tags: javascript

I have a project data that has list of projects and associated employees. Each employee object has `salary` property. What I'm trying to do is to find the employee with maximum salary.

Example of code:

```js
var projects = [
  //Object(0)  
  {
    projectName: "Winter",
    projectCode: "O0123",
    employee: [{
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Tom",
        id: 1005,
        salary: 12345
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Bunny",
        id: 1009,
        salary: 54321
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Harris",
        id: 1010,
        salary: 23456
      },
    ]
  },
  //Object(1)
  {
    projectName: "Summer",
    projectCode: "P10406",
    employee: [{
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Seth",
        id: 1006,
        salary: 1234
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Sam",
        id: 1011,
        salary: 654321
      },
    ],
  }
]


console.log(projects.length);

let maxSalary = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
  console.log(projects[i].projectName);

  for (var j = 0; j < projects[i].employee.length; j++) {
    console.log("\t" + projects[i].employee[j].title + projects[i].employee[j].name + "\n" + "\t" + "Salary: " + projects[i].employee[j].salary);

    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      maxSalary <= projects[i].employee[j].salary;
    }

    if (projects[i].employee[j].salary > maxSalary) {
      maxSalary = projects[i].employee[j].salary;
    }
  }
}

console.log("Max Salary = " + maxSalary);
```

Please suggest any inputs.

Comment: I meant wanted to find out employee with highest salary.

Comment: use jquery filter method to achieve that.

Comment: Then edit your question accordingly, and could you please paste your code in the editor please? Click the icon with the brackets:`<>`

Comment: What is your question? What error/unexpected result did you get? You already found the maximum salary. If your goal is to find the employee, you should store the `i` and `j` value instead of the value of salary.

Comment: @dhavalpawale I tried to reword the question so that its easier for everyone to understand. I was not sure as to, *employee with max salary for every project* or *employee with maximum salary across projects*. My assumption is the latter statement. Nonetheless, please update any information that might mislead

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you for rewording. I am trying to find out employee with highest salary across projects. Sorry for posting it wrongly. I am still a newbie to coding and stackoverflow.

Comment: Not an efficient one, but it is a little bit clearer to understand https://jsbin.com/hoyozomogi/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop through the different `projects` and then loop the `employees` to get the highest value.

```js
var projects = [{
    projectName: "Winter",
    projectCode: "O0123",
    employee: [
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Tom", id: 1005, salary: 12345},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Bunny", id: 1009, salary: 54321},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Harris", id: 1010, salary: 23456}
    ]
  },
  {
    projectName: "Summer",
    projectCode: "P10406",
    employee: [
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Seth", id: 1006, salary: 1234},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Sam", id: 1011, salary: 654321}
    ]
  }
];

var max = 0;
projects.forEach(p => p.employee.forEach(e => e.salary > max && (max = e.salary)));

console.log(max);
```

If you want to receive the `employee`, as you mentioned in your question, and not the salary, you could do it basically the same, just returning the whole `object`:

```js
var projects = [{
    projectName: "Winter",
    projectCode: "O0123",
    employee: [
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Tom", id: 1005, salary: 12345},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Bunny", id: 1009, salary: 54321},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Harris", id: 1010, salary: 23456}
    ]
  },
  {
    projectName: "Summer",
    projectCode: "P10406",
    employee: [
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Seth", id: 1006, salary: 1234},
      {title: "Mr.", name: "Sam", id: 1011, salary: 654321}
    ]
  }
];

var max = {salary: 0};
projects.forEach(p => p.employee.forEach(e => e.salary > max.salary && (max = e)));

console.log(max);
```

I think these examples will give you a basic idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

here you have to mix [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flatMap) which will transform your array of array to simple flat array.

then you can use [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to pick up the highest salary.

```
const projects = [
    {
        employee: [{
                salary: 12345
            },
            {
                salary: 54321
            },
            {
                salary: 23456
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        employee: [{
                salary: 1234
            },
            {
                salary: 654321
            },
        ]
    }  
];

const salaries = projects.flatMap(project => {
    // here we have array of array, goal is to craft flat array of salary.

    return project.employee.map(employe => {
        // From each employee, we pickup only the salary.
        return employe.salary;
    });

});

const highest = salaries.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    // If current salary is highest than the previous, we keep track of it.
    if(currentValue > accumulator) {
        accumulator = currentValue;
    }
    return accumulator;
});
```

Comment: flatmap is an experimental feature not supported by most browsers

Comment: is true, but you can find many polyfill which will do the job for you :).

Answer (score 0):

You already have the maximum salary, what you need to do is save the index of the employee with the highest salary as soon as you get it. You code should look like this.

```js
var projects = [
  //Object(0)  
  {
    projectName: "Winter",
    projectCode: "O0123",
    employee: [{
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Tom",
        id: 1005,
        salary: 12345
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Bunny",
        id: 1009,
        salary: 54321
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Harris",
        id: 1010,
        salary: 23456
      },
    ]
  },
  //Object(1)
  {
    projectName: "Summer",
    projectCode: "P10406",
    employee: [{
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Seth",
        id: 1006,
        salary: 1234
      },
      {
        title: "Mr.",
        name: "Sam",
        id: 1011,
        salary: 654321
      },
    ],
  }
]


console.log(projects.length);

let maxSalary = 0;
let employeeWithMaxSalary = {};

for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
  console.log(projects[i].projectName);

  for (var j = 0; j < projects[i].employee.length; j++) {
    console.log("\t" + projects[i].employee[j].title + projects[i].employee[j].name + "\n" + "\t" + "Salary: " + projects[i].employee[j].salary);

    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      maxSalary <= projects[i].employee[j].salary;
    }

    if (projects[i].employee[j].salary > maxSalary) {
      maxSalary = projects[i].employee[j].salary;
      employeeWithMaxSalary = projects[i].employee[j];
    }
  }
}

console.log("Max Salary = " + maxSalary);
console.log(employeeWithMaxSalary);
```

You can improve also improve your code by using ES6 syntax (arrow function and `foreach`) instead of having nested loops.